# How do I make "find" only match files in specific sub-directories

Tags: macos, bash, find

I'm using bash for Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Using the `find` command, I would like to search for files that match `*.XML`.  However, I would like to match only those files in the `16xxxx` sub-directory and not `16yyyy` from some base directory.

```
basedir/16xxxx/EX1.XML
basedir/16xxxx/EX2.XML
basedir/16yyyy/EX3.XML
basedir/16yyyy/EX4.XML
```

The results I'm looking for would be `EX1.XML` and `EX2.XML` (full path name excluded for clarity).

This is in the context of a BASH script which would make it convenient if I could enter `16xxxx/*.XML` as the expression to pass to `-name` in the `find` command:

```
find basedir -name '16xxxx/*.XML'
```

However, this does not return any matches because the shell doesn't match the `/` character.  Is there some argument to pass to `find` or a way to escape the `16xxxx/\*.XML` expression that will return the results I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-name` option is never going to work past the first `/`. As always, [man](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) pages are your friends:

```
 -path pattern
         True if the pathname being examined matches pattern.  Special shell pattern matching characters
         (``['', ``]'', ``*'', and ``?'') may be used as part of pattern.  These characters may be
         matched explicitly by escaping them with a backslash (``\'').  Slashes (``/'') are treated as
         normal characters and do not have to be matched explicitly.
```

I usually prefer compatibility with GNU find, and therefore use the `-wholename` option. Nothe that these also exist in case-insensitive mode: `-iwholename` and `-ipath`.

So in your case, you'd do (remember that wholename matches the *whole* path, so you have to add the wildcard `*` at the beginning):

```
karolos$ find basedir -type f
basedir/16xxxx/EX1.XML
basedir/16xxxx/EX2.XML
basedir/16yyyy/EX3.XML
basedir/16yyyy/EX4.XML
karolos$ find basedir -wholename "*16xxxx/*.XML"
basedir/16xxxx/EX1.XML
basedir/16xxxx/EX2.XML
```

Another way to achieve what you want is to use find in combination with `grep` (note that I had to alter the regular expression, adding a `.` (for any caracter) before the wildcard `*`):

```
karolos$ find basedir | grep '16xxxx/.*.XML'
basedir/16xxxx/EX1.XML
basedir/16xxxx/EX2.XML
```

Finally, depending on your needs, there is even the possibility that you *don't* even need to use `find` (if you don't need the extra flexibility). You can then use `bash` [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) as follows:

```
karolos$ echo basename/*16x*/*XML
basename/16xxxx/EX1.XML basename/16xxxx/EX2.XML
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I tried -wholename during my efforts yesterday but didn't try the wildcard.  I tried my best to avoid the RTFM comments (I read the manual), but I'll need to try harder ;)

Comment: @stever: You're welcome. Manual pages for GNU tools are usually well documented, but the *nix jargon is not always straightforward at first. The leading wildcard catch is indeed something easy to miss.